# the error in python greedy matching

Tags: python, regex, matching, greedy

```
import re
greedyHaRegex = re.compile(r'(Ha){3, 5}')
mo1 = greedyHaRegex.search('HaHaHaHaHa')
mo1.group()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    mo1.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I don't understand why this error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is not matching because of the extra space in the quantifier `{3, 5}`, thus `search()` returns `None` Remove the space and it and it will match.
Use for example [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3Ob12C/1) to debug such thing.